# Extracting Data from xml file using SimpleXml

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

Hello I am trying to extract data from an **XML** file using [SimpleXml](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) but it's not extracting the `LA 1` from `display-name` tag

This is the XML :

```
<tv generator-info-name="munich" generator-info-url="http://test.com">
    <channel id="254">
        <display-name lang="es">LA 1</display-name>
    </channel>
</tv>
```

This is my code which I am using to extract the `id` attribute from `channel` tag :

```
 $epg = simplexml_load_file("epg.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");
 foreach($epg->channel as $canal) {
     echo $canal[id];
 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the name of the element you want to display has a `-` in it, you will need to output the element using (I cast it to a string just to be pedantic)...

```
echo (string)$canal->{'display-name'};
```

Using

```
$canal->display-name
```

will be interpreted as `$canal->display` minus `name`.

Comment: `$canal->display-name` very true about that.. i even forgot that was a thing.. the topicstarter is beter off using `display_name` in the XML.so `$canal->display_name` can be used but matter of taste i guess.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `xml_parser_create`

```
$xml = '<tv generator-info-name="munich" generator-info-url="http://test.com">
   <channel id="254">
    <display-name lang="es">LA 1</display-name>
   </channel>
</tv>';
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($string);
echo $xml->xpath('//display-name')[0];
```

Comment: You can, but I don't know why you'd ever want to. That function is more like the building block for writing your own parser than a parser in its own right.